# A locally compact, complete metric space in which the closure of open balls coincide with the closed ball is Heine-Borel

Tags: reference-request, gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, metric-spaces

I saw the following result stated without a proof in a paper about the isometry group of metric measure spaces:

Let $X$ be a locally compact, complete metric space such that for all $x \in X$ and $R > 0$, then $\overline{B(x,R)} = B[x,R]$. Then the space have the Heine-Borel property, that is, every closed and bounded subset of $X$ is compact.

I'm aware of a proof for this result by changing "closure of ball = closed ball" to "$X$ is an length space", which can be found in Burago's, Yuri's and Ivanov's book. However, that proof relies on the $\varepsilon$-midpoint property of length spaces, which seems stronger than what "closure of ball = closed ball" provides. I was unable to adapt that proof for this case, and I'm not even convinced that this should be true anymore.

I was hoping if this result is written or know somewhere.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The paper in question is the following:

[1] Sosa, Gerardo. "The Isometry Group of an RCD∗ space is Lie." Potential Analysis 49.2 (2018): 267-286.

The result is stated in a footnote of proposition 3.6.

Comment: Yuri is also Burago:)

Comment: I know, but "burago, burago" is kinda confusing to say.

Comment: Can you include a reference to the paper stating the result?

Comment: @YuvalPeres I added the paper in the edit.

Comment: What about $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\frac{|x-y|}{|x-y|+1}$?

Comment: @Echo Isn't your comment worth an answer?